# Что означает `@` (собака) в пути файла?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

С помощью утилиты [`vue-cli`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) создал шаблон приложения под `webpack`.
В файле `./src/router/index.js` обнаружил такую строку:

```
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'
```

Что означает `@` (собака) в пути файла?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите в файл `build\webpack.base.conf.js`, это alias который ссылается на определенный путь, по умолчанию на 'path to project/src/'.

Comment: хм... при том, что сам по себе символ "@" вполне легитимен для использования в имени файла. Или там ещё и позиционная зависимость - строго в начале литерала?

Comment: На сто процентов не понял из доки вебпака, как он этот алиас заменяет - первый попавшийся/только сначала/все вхождения. Если, нужно, то его можно заменить на свой.